# Which has highest solubility in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Among $\ce{LiF}$, $\ce{LiCl}$, $\ce{LiBr}$ and $\ce{LiI}$ is $\ce{LiI}$ the most soluble compound ? As the lattice energy depends on size and smaller the size of ions greater the lattice and as $\ce{LiI}$ has greater size therefore should it be most soluble? Since lattice energy is inversely proportional to solubility, according to me $\ce{LiI}$ is most soluble and $\ce{LiF}$ is least. Is this correct ?

Comment: Soluble in water?

Comment: $\ce{LiI}$ is less soluble than $\ce{LiCl}$ in terms of moles per liter, while $\ce{LiF}$ is the least soluble of all.